# How to make the multibox values selected in html:select in struts?

Tags: web-applications, struts

In my application I am using multibox where I have 5 values and want first 3 values to be preselected. So How could I make it at the time when i am creating the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for your problem will be write a javascript at the end of your JSP and select what ever values you wanted to select.

The permanent and critical solution will be write your own tag extending **org.apache.struts.taglib.html.OptionTag** and use that in your struts file.